# The [phoenix] tag vs the [phoenix-framework] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix) tag has less than 800 questions.

The [phoenix-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) tag has over 3000 questions.

A good portion of the questions tagged [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix) are actually about [phoenix-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework).

Maybe it's time to make [phoenix-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) be the default meaning for [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix), or at least to rename [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix) to something more specific like [apache-phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-phoenix)?

Comment: Changing the default the other direction would only change which tool's tag got the incorrectly tagged questions.  If we do something, cleaning out phoenix and renaming it apache-phoenix would be the way to go.

Comment: I created the `apache-phoenix` tag. I might start retagging the `phoenix` questions, but there's 940 of them... Are there moderator tools to do this for people with more privileges?

Answer (score 4):

*(disclaimer: I do not have tag badges in these technologies, but I'm familiar with elixir and at times browse elixir questions)*

I think the tag needs disambiguation. It's better to end up with `apache-phoenix` and `phoenix-framework` and drop `phoenix` which is unspecific and likely to cause confusion.

Given the amount of questions tagged `phoenix` *and not* `elixir` (correct) (721), vs. questions tagged `phoenix` *and* `elixir` (incorrect) (209) — where correctness is based on the current tag wiki excerpt of `phoenix`, it's probably best to disambiguate first, and then rename `phoenix` to `apache-phoenix`.

I suggest the following course of action:

- retag questions tagged [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix)+[elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir) with [phoenix-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) <strike>(209 questions)</strike> (done)
- remove tag [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix) from those already tagged [phoenix-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) <strike>(43 questions)</strike> (done)
- rename [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix) to [apache-phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-phoenix) (this can be done by a moderator) (done)
- optional: add [elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir) to questions already tagged [phoenix-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) (455 questions)

Comment: Sounds good to me! We can also retag the `phoenix` questions without `elixir` that are obviously about the Phoenix Framework to `phoenix-framework` and `elixir`.